How to draw a grid in canvas?
I'm trying to draw a grid in flutter canvas with flame framework but really having a hard time. This is my current code that I'm using to draw the grid:
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flame/components.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:learning_flame/my_game.dart';

class GameBoard extends PositionComponent with HasGameRef<MyGame> {
  @override
  FutureOr<void> onLoad() {
    super.onLoad();

    // game size
    final gameSize = gameRef.size;
    const cellSize = 40.0;
    const cellSpacing = 10.0;

    // starting position
    final startingPosition = Vector2(-(gameSize.x / 2) + cellSize, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        add(
          Cell(
            position: startingPosition +
                Vector2(
                  (cellSize + cellSpacing) * j,
                  i * (cellSize + cellSpacing),
                ),
            size: Vector2.all(cellSize),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
  }
}

class Cell extends RectangleComponent {
  Cell({
    required super.position,
    required super.size,
  }) : super(anchor: Anchor.center);

  @override
  void render(Canvas canvas) {
    super.render(canvas);

    canvas.drawRect(
      Rect.fromCenter(
        center: Offset.zero,
        width: position.y,
        height: position.x,
      ),
      paint..color = Colors.white,
    );
  }
}

This is the result I'm getting:

Expected results
I was expective a 5x5 grid to be drawn on the canvas with the code provided.

This fixes the issue:
https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/issues/3337
I was not using the RectangleComponent properly.
